# Single Select query to Select 3 different variable based on 3 different condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to write below SQL query in Single Select query,

```
SET @T1 = COUNT(1) FROM @TableVar
SET @T2 = COUNT(1) FROM @TableVar WHERE bit1 = 1 AND bit2 = 0
SET @T3 = COUNT(1) FROM @TableVar WHERE bit1 = 0 AND bit2 = 1

SELECT @T1 AS Col1,
       @T2 AS Col2,
       @T3 AS Col3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT T1 = COUNT(1),
       T2 = COUNT(CASE WHEN bit1 = 1 AND bit2 = 0 THEN 1 END),
       T3 = COUNT(CASE WHEN bit1 = 0 AND bit2 = 1 THEN 1 END)
FROM @TableVar
```

Comment: Can you just tell me which one is best as performance wise. Should I use `SUM()` or `COUNT()` in this case? As I have large number of data in this `@TableVar`

Comment: In your case `COUNT` is more preferable.... Check this post - http://blog.devart.com/fastest_way_to_calculate_the_record_count.html

Comment: Please provide columns with datatype in your table

Comment: Thanks for that link, I will use `COUNT()` - My table structure is bit complex still your answer helped me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/6723)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE  @TableVar TABLE
(bit1 bit, bit2 bit)

INSERT INTO @TableVar Values(0,0)
INSERT INTO @TableVar Values(1,1)
INSERT INTO @TableVar Values(1,0)
INSERT INTO @TableVar Values(1,0)
INSERT INTO @TableVar Values(0,1)


SELECT COUNT(1) AS Col1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN bit1=1 and bit2=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Col2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN bit1=0 AND bit2=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Col3
FROM @TableVar
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/6723/0)**:

```
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
|------|------|------|
|    5 |    2 |    1 |
```

Comment: Thanks for giving answer with fiddle demo link. Can you just tell me which one is best as performance wise. Should I use `SUM()` or `COUNT()` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

this is how i would do:

```
select count(*),
(select count(*) from @TableVar WHERE bit1 = 1 AND bit2 = 0) as col2,
(select count(*) from @TableVar WHERE bit1 = 0 AND bit2 = 1) as col3  from @TableVar
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you just tell me which one is best as performance wise. Should I use `SUM()` or `COUNT()` in this case? As I have large number of data in this `@TableVar`

Comment: i don't know which takes more time, you can test them both with a timer and see for yourself, also if you test can you tell me which is better?

Comment: currently working on local so it will work fast. but I am asking as on live it will definitely take more time so....

Comment: do you need to count the number of rows or do you need the summary of every row content?